# Control Flags in Interrupt Routine and NMI [8086]

Tags: interrupt, masm, flags, x86-16

I know how an interrupt routine is executed in 8086. The thing that isn't clear to me is how different types of interrupts (i.e hardware, software and exception) uses the control flags (Interrupt Flag and Trap Flag) in their execution.
And other thing is what is **Non-mask-able Interrupts** and its use?
So please help me with this, Thanks.

Comment: They don't.  Read-up on what the [PIC does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_Interrupt_Controller).

Comment: But i read in a book that the IF and trap flag are cleared when a software interrupt is encountered

Comment: Sure, they get cleared on *any* interrupt, hardware or software or nmi.  So they don't tell you anything at all about the specific interrupt.

Comment: I get that. The thing i want to know is what happens when our IF and TF is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interrupt handler doesn't "do" anything with the IF and TF flags. They are cleared so the interrupt handler can do its job properly and safely. You need to understand what those flags do, then it becomes obvious why they are cleared during an interrupt.

When the **Interrupt Flag** or **IF** is set, the processor will allow external hardware signals (usually from a Programmable Interrupt Controller or PIC) to trigger interrupts. When it's cleared, hardware interrupt signals are ignored.

(The **NMI** or **Non-Maskable Interrupt** is an exception, a special case intended for "emergency-type" or "real-time" events, and it will trigger even if the IF is cleared.)

The **Trap Flag** or **TF** is used by debuggers. When the flag is set, the processor will execute *exactly one* instruction, then trigger an INT 1. A debugger can use this to single-step machine code without having to temporarily modify it (e.g. to temporarily insert an INT 3 instruction), which is not always even possible (e.g. single-stepping code stored in ROM).

Now why are both flags cleared during interrupts?

The IF is cleared because Intel didn't want to impose the restriction that interrupt handlers be reentrant. Reentrant code is code that can be safely suspended at any time, and called again from the top. If you allow interrupts while an interrupt handler is running, it is quite possible for a second interrupt to trigger while in the middle of handling the first one, which would cause the handle to re-enter. Note that software interrupt handlers (like the DOS interrupt handler 21h) typically don't have this concern because they are not called by asynchronous hardware signals; therefore, just about the first thing they do is execute `STI` to re-enable interrupts.

The situation with TF is very similar but a bit trickier to understand. I don't have experience writing an x86 debugger, so I don't know the ins-and outs. The short version is that the TF is cleared during interrupts to avoid chaos. What follows is a speculative excercise of mine.

First of all, it should be obvious that at least the single-step interrupt (type-1 or INT 1 if you will) MUST clear the flag, otherwise the debugger's single-step handler *itself* would trigger single-step interrupts or not run at all. Second, let's imagine that the TF is not cleared for every interrupt: if a hardware interrupt triggers while the debugger is trying to use the TF, the interrupt handler itself might be the one triggering the single-step interrupt, instead of the code being debugged. Worse, now the interrupts are suspended (see **IF** above) and not only are you looking at the wrong code (or thoroughly confused the debugger), but *your keyboard doesn't work anymore*. (As I said, I'm speculating: I have no idea what happens if **IF** is cleared but **TF** is set).

Asynchronous hardware interrupts need to be handled without "bothering" the current running program, that is, they need to execute without the program being aware of them. That includes "not bothering" a single-stepping debugger.